# Tiny Deathstar crashes while loading

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

When I tap on the Tiny Deathstar icon everything seems normal. The loading screen popps up and the gamecenter welcomes me. As soon as the loading bar reaches about a quarter the app crashes. This happens everytime and I habe only been playing since yesterday. Anyone here who can help me?

Comment: Game is available on iOS, Android and Windows and probably crashes on each of these are different. Can you tell us what system are you using? Also, have you considered asking their customer service?

Comment: OP mentioned Gamecenter - I am assuming iOS.  Have you tried deleting the app and re-installing it?   Caution - you might lose all of your gameplay if it was never set up to save backups of your progress to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem, from about mid-March the app would crash upon launching for me under iOS on an iPad 2.  I saw that many others had similar problems and stopped playing, obviously, as it crashed upon launch.  However, the most recent update 1.4.2 (of Aug 7th 2014) worked well for me, first under iOS 6 and now under iOS 7 with all my earlier progress restored.